# Use the name of the table from Amazon RDS in the output csv being sent to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-data-pipeline

I successfully managed to get a data pipeline to transfer data from a set of tables in Amazon RDS (Aurora) to a set of .csv files in S3 with a "copyActivity" connecting the two DataNodes.

However, I'd like the .csv file to have the name of the table (or view) that it came from.  I can't quite figure out how to do this.  I think the best approach is to use an expression the filePath parameter of the S3 DataNode.

But, I've tried `#{table}`, `#{node.table}`, `#{parent.table}`, and a variety of combinations of `node.id` and `parent.name` without success.

Here's a couple of JSON snippets from my pipeline:

```
"database": {
    "ref": "DatabaseId_abc123"
  },
  "name": "Foo",
  "id": "DataNodeId_xyz321",
  "type": "MySqlDataNode",
  "table": "table_foo",
  "selectQuery": "select * from #{table}"
},
{
  "schedule": {
    "ref": "DefaultSchedule"
  },
  "filePath": "#{myOutputS3Loc}/#{parent.node.table.help.me.here}.csv",
  "name": "S3_BAR_Bucket",
  "id": "DataNodeId_w7x8y9",
  "type": "S3DataNode"
}
```

Any advice you can provide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have #{table} (did you mean #{myTable}?).  If you are using a parameter to pass the name of the DB table, you can use that in the S3 filepath as well like this:

"filePath": "#{myOutputS3Loc}/#{myTable}.csv",

Comment: thanks.  No, looks like I haven't been clear, sorry.  The name of the DB tables are hard coded in the data nodes (I have 4 source nodes).  That gives me an idea though, I wonder if there is a way to use separate "my" parameters for the data nodes and then individually reference them in the output data node?